# Python: drop duplicates by conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have data on some positions with term starting month and term end month.

```
Name   Year   Month   Start
A      1994   05       1
A      1996   04       0
B      1996   04       1
B      1996   12       0
C      1996   12       1
C      1999   02       0
```

Column `Start` equals `1` means the person starts in this month, `0` means he/she leaves the position in this month.

I need to convert this monthly data into a yearly data, i.e. assign who is in that position in a given year. My idea is to find the person who stays more than half a year on that position. That is, I want to achieve:

```
Year    Name
1994    A
1995    A
1996    B
1997    C
1998    C
```

I think I need to drop duplicates based on `df['Year']`.

I can do `df_annual = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Year'])` To take into account term length, I think it works to drop the duplicate if `df['Month']<'06'` and `Start == 0`, or if `df['Month']>'06'` and `Start == 1`. That is, they leave in the second half of the year or start the term in the first half of the year.

In general, the question boils down to how to select one row if they have the same `'Year'`.

Does anyone know how to do this in python?

Comment: Why is C suddenly starting in `1997`?

Comment: C starts the position in December 1996, so in the annual data, C doesn't have enough time on the position in 1996. However, he does have the whole year of 1997.

Comment: If you know their position, you can just index them using .iloc https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Comment: @samman what should he do if he has a million rows of data? Should he manually go through each row? What if this is a process that needs to be run daily? Should he do this each time? What if he had to take a sick day or go on PTO, would he have to train another colleague on how to look up all the rows and manually type them into a list in preparation for .iloc? This is not a solution to the question specified.

Comment: @DavidErickson there was no answer when I made that comment, which is also why it was a comment instead of an answer (many questions go unanswered, I thought it'd be better to leave a comment with some type of help rather than nothing at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit logic here for the first line, we do adjust `year` when the `month` is greater than 6 for start and the `month` is less than 6 for the end.

```
# if the month start is greater the 6 you do not want it that year count, for the end month same. 
df.Year=np.where(df.Start==1, (df.Month>=6)+df.Year, df.Year-(df.Month<=6))
s=df.pivot('Name','Start','Year')
s['New']=[range(x, y+1) for x , y in zip(s[1],s[0])]

s=s['New'].explode().drop_duplicates(keep='last')
Name
A    1994
A    1995
B    1996
C    1997
C    1998
Name: New, dtype: object
```

Comment: great answer +1, getting the min year and max year by group, zipping into a range and exploding is much better that reindexing, which I struggle with!

Comment: Thanks, I also like how you nested two different pieces of logic in your `np.where` for two different outcomes. Much more efficient. I didn't know you could do that... as you can see from my more complicated `np.where()` statements.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This is magical. When I do the `pivot`, it says `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`. Can I ask is there a way to fix this? Sorry for the additional question. This is really beyond the main question.

Comment: @Tian I think you can drop duplicate before doing that ~ df.drop_dfuplicates().pivot('Name','Start','Year')

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4):

This one was pretty tough. I chose to reindex in order to get in missing years like 1997 and 1998. Then, I used `ffill()` to fill down the `Start` column in preparation for a lot of `np.where` logic that was used to drop unnecessary rows.

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'C', 5: 'C'},
 'Year': {0: 1994, 1: 1996, 2: 1996, 3: 1996, 4: 1996, 5: 1999},
 'Month': {0: 5, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 12, 4: 12, 5: 2},
 'Start': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 0}})
```

code:

```
#reindexing to get missing years
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format='%Y')
df = (df.set_index('dt').groupby('Name')
             .apply(lambda d: d.reindex(pd.date_range(min(df.dt),
                                                      max(df.dt),
                                                      freq='YS')))
             .drop('Name', axis=1)
             .reset_index('Name').reset_index())
#specified logic to keep relevant rows and columns
df['Start'] = df['Start'].ffill()
m1 = np.where(~((df['Start'] == df['Start'].shift())
                     & (df['Start'] == 0)
                      & (df['Start'].shift() == 0))
                      | (df['Year'].notnull()),
                     'keep', 'drop')
df = df[m1 == 'keep']
m2 = np.where(((df['Month']< int('06')) & (df['Start'] == 0))
             | ((df['Month']>int('06')) & (df['Start'] == 1)),
                      'drop', 'keep')
df = df[m2 == 'keep']
df['Year'] = df['index'].dt.year
df = df.drop(['index', 'Month', 'Start'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

output:

```
    Name Year
0   A    1994
1   A    1995
2   B    1996
3   C    1997
4   C    1998
```

Comment: Thank you so much for spending time on this! I really appreciate your help as well!